# Why is safari changing the html code from "jquery.js" to "â€œjquery.jsâ€"? then throws "URL not found"

Tags: javascript, html, safari, textedit

I am new to web development on mac, and am trying to add jquery to my website. I downloaded jquery and saved it as jquery.js in the same folder as the html file. I then linked it into my html file using:

`<script src="jquery.js"></script>`

However, when I open the file in safari the html is changed to this, and then it throws an error "the requested URL was not found on this server"

```
<script src="â€œjquery.jsâ€"></script>
```

I am guessing it is something to do with the extra characters added, could anyone please explain this?

Comment: Safari simply will not do that. If your link were really exactly what you've typed in this question, it would work. Apparently the actual content of your file has some hidden/invisible characters. Delete the line and replace it with a copy-and-paste from your question above (which is clean).

Comment: Thanks for the advice, this fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's because in the HTML file you are not using the character `"`. You are using `“` and `”`. You should use `"` when surrounding attribute values.

**Update**

This is likely happening because your UTF-8 encoded HTML file is being interpreted as [ISO-8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1).

In UTF-8 [LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/201C/index.htm) in hex is `0xE2809C`. 
Interpreted in ISO-8859-1:

`E2 = â`

`80 = €`

`9C = œ`

In UTF-8 [RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/201d/index.htm) in hex is `0xE2809D`

`E2 = â`

`80 = €`

`9D =` (UNASSIGNED)

The quote is put in there by the browser. It actually adds the proper `"` quotes around the attribute value.

Comment: I think this is likely to be correct. Still doesn't match the OP's quoted text, which (again) *includes a quote*, it isn't just `â€œ` (according to the question). That said, I suspect it's just that the question is wrong. Or more likely, since there weren't any (real) quotes, they copied that from the DOM view, which added them.

Comment: Put in by the browser. So it encloses his incorrect `“jquery.js”` with the proper quotes: `"`. If you check for example: `<div id=something></div>` it will be in the DOM as `<div id="something"></div>`. So the `“jquery.js”` is interpreted as an attribute value without quotes, so the browser just puts quotes around it. At least this is my guess of what is happening here.